# Angular. Watching a service for changes?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, binding

You have a service called "**DataService**" which houses a closure.
The closure properties can be get / set / displayed via get/set/display(ClosurePropertyName):

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.service('DataService', [function(){
      var data = this;
    (function initialize() {
    var closure = {
        prop: 'etc',
        otherProp: [],
        diffProp: {
            a: 'b',
            c: 'd'
        }
    }, keys = Object.keys(closure);

    // ex: data.displayProp() 
    // returns : Displaying etc
    data.displayProp = function () {
        return 'Displaying: ' + closure.prop;
    }


    // ex: data.getProp() 
    // returns : etc
    data.getProp = function () {
        return closure.prop;
    }
    // ex: data.setProp("derp");
    // becomes: closure.prop = "derp"
    data.setProp = function (val) {
        closure.prop = val;
    }
    data.allProps = function () {
        var obj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            obj[keys[i]] = closure[keys[i]];
        }
        return obj;
    }
    })();
}]);
```

You have controllers accessing this service:

```
  app.controller('CntrlA', ['$scope', 'DataService', function($scope, DataService){  
     var props = DataService.allProps();
     this.props = props;
     this.changeProp = function(val){
       DataService.setProp(val);
     }

     $scope.CntrlA = this;
     return $scope.CntrlA;
   }]);

   app.controller('CntrlB',  ['$scope', 'DataService', function($scope, DataService){
     var props = DataService.allProps();
      this.changeOtherProps = function(arr){
        DataService.setOtherProp(arr);
     }
     $scope.CntrlB = this;
     return $scope.CntrlB
   }]);
```

And simple html:

```
body[ng-app="app"]

  div[ng-controller="CntrlA as aa"]
    button[ng-click="aa.changeProp('herp a derp')"]
    div "{{aa.props}}"

  div[ng-controller="CntrlB as bb"]
    button[ng-click="bb.setOtherProp(['all', 'the', 'things'])"]
    div "{{bb.props}}"
```

How do you get changes to apply to both when the value changes? I know this has to be simple, but $scope.$watch doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$watch` would in this case look something like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return DataService.allProps();
  },
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) return;
    $scope.CntrlA.props = newValue;
  }, true);
```

Since `allProps` returns a new object reference each time, you need to pass `true` as the third argument. Otherwise you will get the "Infinite $digest Loop"-error.

However, using `$watch` in this case will not be efficient at all. Every digest loop contains multiple digest cycles, and each cycle would perform `DataService.allProps()` and the iteration therein. And since you have to pass `true` as the third parameter to `$watch` it will use `angular.equals` and `angular.copy` internally, which involves even more expensive operations.

**Demo with `$watch` (chech the console):** http://plnkr.co/edit/DLmT5XAPBXA3dg5DENRS?p=preview

If your service needs to look like this a better solution would to instead fire an event each time a property changes. This way the digest cycle would not be burdened.

For example:

```
data.setProp = function(val) {
  closure.prop = val;
  $rootScope.$emit('DataService:update');
};
```

And in controller:

```
var unregister = $rootScope.$on('DataService:update', function() {
  $scope.CntrlA.props = DataService.allProps();
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', unregister);
```

**Demo with $emit:** http://plnkr.co/edit/QfdqGsLVXYnL4HIy82gk?p=preview

Comment: Nice. Thanks, man :-)        You say that 'if your service needs to look like this'... I've actually been trying to figure out if I'm using the best angular element type for this kind of thing- any chance you can touch on how you would structure the service instead? would you still have it be a service?